# Run output of command as powershell incantation

Tags: powershell

I have a bash script that generates a program incantation (`docker run ...` with a bunch of arguments) and prints it to standard output. I want to run the output from powershell, with the optional possibility to tack on other arguments afterwards.

I've tried

```
D:\> & $(wsl ./my-bash-script.sh) some more args
```

but I get the error

> The term 'docker run --rm -ti [<redacted>]' is not recognized as the name of cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or ifa  path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Apparently, `&` interprets the entire output as a single command, when in fact it's only the *first word* of the output that is a command; the rest is arguments.

Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `&` only supports a command name or path as its first argument - you cannot include arguments.

What you need is [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression):

```
Invoke-Expression "$(wsl ./my-bash-script.sh) some more args"
```

<sup>Note: You'd only need `&` inside the string if the `.sh` script output a command with a *quoted* executable path.</sup>

Also note that PowerShell will not always interpret a given command line the same way as a POSIX-like shell (such as Bash), given that it recognizes additional metacharacters at the start of arguments; notably, arguments prefixed with `@` or `{` will not be taken as literals by PowerShell.

As an aside: While this is a legitimate use case for `Invoke-Expression` - assuming you trust the output from your `.sh` script -  [Invoke-Expression should generally be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).

Comment: Yes, in this case I do trust the output of the shell script; it is a convenience script which basically downloads a connection string to my Azure PostgreSQL instance and puts together a Docker command that connects to it. It has to be a bash-script so my colleagues using Mac and Ubuntu can use it, but I have to be able to call it from Powershell because WSL doesn't fully support TTY. This neatly solves both - thanks!